# As per CA1008 rule of FXCop Enums should have a default value of zero. Is this applicable for C#?

Tags: c#, enums, fxcop

Should this rule be applicable to C#?

The compiler gives error "Use of unassigned local variable" if we try to use the enum without explicitly setting a value?

**The perspective being asked is the validity of the FxCop rule since I cannot use the default value of an enum.**

```
public enum TraceLevel
{
    Off = 0,
    Error = 1,
    Warning = 2,
    Info = 3,
    Verbose = 4
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TraceLevel traceLevelOptions;
        Console.WriteLine(traceLevelOptions.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Updated after getting the right answer. The following code should work:**

```
public class SerializeMe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TraceLevel MyTrace { get; set; }
}

public enum TraceLevel
{
    Off = 0,
    Error = 1,
    Warning = 2,
    Info = 3,
    Verbose = 4
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerializeMe serializeMe = new SerializeMe();
        Console.WriteLine(serializeMe.MyTrace.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem of `enum`, you get the same error with every type.

Comment: What does this have to do with FxCop?

Comment: @BoltClock - updated the question to bring more clarity to the perspective. I know that I will get the unassigned error. That is the whole point of questioning the rule framed in FxCop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that enums should have a zero value is explained in the documentation for the Code Analysis error that relates to it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx

**CA1008: Enums should have zero value**

*The default value of an uninitialized enumeration, just like other value types, is zero. A non-flags−attributed enumeration should define a member that has the value of zero so that the default value is a valid value of the enumeration.*

So the reason is that if, for example, you declare an enum field in a class or struct and do not initialise it, it will have the default value of zero. If there is no member of the enum with a zero value, you will in that (fairly common) situation have a enum field containing an invalid value.

There are also other instances where you can end up with a default-initialised enum field (e.g. during deserialization). You want to avoid a default-initialised enum field having an invalid value, hence the rule.

Comment: +1 for explaining the FXCop rule instead of changing the subject! :)

Comment: @Matthew Watson - Thanks for adding the details for serialization / deserialization. As a property, the compiler allowed the code to compile even though I still did not explicitly initialize it and I could also get the default value.

Comment: The code that finally worked: public class SerializeMe
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public TraceLevel MyTrace { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TraceLevel
    {
        Off = 0,
        Error = 1,
        Warning = 2,
        Info = 3,
        Verbose = 4
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerializeMe serializeMe = new SerializeMe();
            Console.WriteLine(serializeMe.MyTrace.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a FXCop error, it is a C# compiler error. In C# all the local variables must be initialized before being used.

```
TraceLevel traceLevelOptions = 0; // or TraceLevel.Error for example
```

Like for all the other types... If `traceLevelOptions` was an `int`, you would get the same error.

There is a loophole for `struct` types. You can assign them with a value or assign all their fields with a value, and they will be considered assigned. Note that this condition sometimes can't be satisfied if the `struct` has, for example, `private` fields.

Comment: By default an enum is of the type int :)

Comment: @thmsn - enums do have an integer "underlying type", but an enum variable is a distinct type. It doesn't even have implicit conversion with integers: you have to put in explicit casts, to convert in either direction (from int to enum and vice versa). NB. zero is treated as a special case, as it can occur anyway in an uninitialized field. But you cannot say `traceLevelOptions = 1` even if 1 is an explicitly defined allowed value.